# Sending email via Lotus Notes using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, lotus-notes

I've been studying how to send emails via Lotus Notus but my database is wrong.

I tried to put "", "" without success.

```vb
Dim MailData As Object 'The email database
Dim Maildoc As Object 'The email itself
Dim Session As Object 'The notes session
    
linha = 2

Do Until Cells(linha, 1) = ""

    Set Session = CreateObject("Notes.NotesSession")
    Set MailData = NotesSession.GetDatabase("", "C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Lotus\Notes.exe")

    If MailData.IsOpen = True Then
    Else
        MailData.Openmail
    End If

    Set Maildoc = MailDB.CreateDocument
    Maildoc.SendTo = Cells(linha, 8)
    Maildoc.Subject = "SYMRISE BR - Quotation" & " -" & Cells(linha, 1) & " -" & Cells(linha, 4)
    Maildoc.Body = "Dears, & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & Cells(15,14) & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & Cells(1,1) & "" & Cells(linha, 1) & "
    Chr (10) & Cells(1, 2) & "" & Cells(linha, 2) & Chr(10) & Cells(1, 3) & "" & Cells(linha, 3) & Chr(10) & _
    Cells(1, 4) & " " & Cells(linha, 4) & Chr(10) & Cells(1, 5) & " " & Cells(linha, 5)
    
    Maildoc.SaveMessageonSend = True
   
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use "","" to identify a database in VBA. That works only in LotusScript code that is running inside the Notes client or on a Domino server.

And "C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Lotus\Notes.exe" isn't a database. It's a program. It's the Notes program. A database is a file with a name that ends with ".NSF".

If you want to open the current user's personal email database, then you should be using the [OpenMail](https://help.hcltechsw.com/dom_designer/9.0.1/appdev/H_OPENMAIL_METHOD.html) method of the NotesDatabase[enter link description here](https://help.hcltechsw.com/dom_designer/9.0.1/appdev/H_NOTESDATABASE_CLASS.html) class.